# Odd Cookie Behaviour

Tags: php, cookies

Having a really, really strange problem with setting cookies in PHP. I have basically implemented a login function (really, really run of the mill) and the idea is, if the database returns a row, after being queried with their username and password, then it's all fine.

Code I'm using to query the database (seems to work fine):

```
 $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM staff_accs WHERE username=:username AND password=:password");
    $statement->bindParam(':username', $username);
    $statement->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();
```

The code I'm using to test if a row is returned. Again, seems to be working fine.

```
    if($statement->fetchColumn() === "1")
    {
        $cookieValue = sha1($username.$password);

        setcookie('admin', $cookieValue, 3600, '/');
        $_COOKIE['admin'] = $cookieValue;
        header("Location: ../admin.php");
    }
    else
    {
        // Re-direct to no permissions page.
        header("Location: ../noPermission.html");
    }
```

The code re-directs to the correct page, however, the cookie is not set. I've set the path to "/" to ensure that it is globally available (it wasn't working without the "/"). I am also setting the value directly after calling the method to make sure the cookie is set straight away.

However, when I get to the `admin.html` page, I am calling a `var_dump` of the `$_COOKIE` array, and this is what I'm getting:

```
array(0) { }
```

So it appears the cookie is not being set, despite the fact the correct block of code is running..

Comment: If you remove the redirect, does the cookie get set?

Comment: I've just tested. It, indeed, does get set. Why would a re-direct cause the cookie not to be stored?

Comment: refresh admin.php and check again

Comment: Perhaps the code is going to fast?  Try a delay.  Perhaps the redirecting up 1 level (`../`) is causing the cookie to be in the wrong spot?  Perhaps something on `admin.php` is deleting the cookie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your call to `setcookie`. The third argument expects a timestamp, not a duration. Here, your cookie expires before even existing.
You should try :

```
setcookie('admin', $cookieValue, time() + 3600, '/');
```

Comment: Sweet baby Jesus. I've been programming in PHP for two years; how on earth did I make such a stupid mistake!? Thankyou, I shall accept in 6 minutes. :)

Comment: @Chris : Everybody makes mistakes. In case of doubt, checking the doc is a good habit. ;-)